# SQL Server identity related error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity-column

I am using this query in SQL SERVER 2008..

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ABC ON

BULK 
INSERT ABC
FROM 'F:\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

and getting an error :

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'ABC'
>   either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is
>   inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Table structure for 'ABC' is :

```
ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  -- primary key
aa [varchar](50) NULL,
bb [varchar](50) NULL,
cc [datetime] NULL,
dd [varchar](50) NULL,
ee [varchar](50) NULL,
ff [int] NULL,
gg [varchar](50) NULL,
ii [int] NULL,
jj [int] NULL
```

Sample data from CSV file

```
84,0b0dbe1d,192.168.10.221,2012-07-27 16:15:41.503,0b0dbe1d_16-15-18,1.0.0,2,pra,2,NULL
85,111de4b6,192.168.10.221,2012-07-27 16:27:06.060,111de4b6_16-27-05,1.0.0,8,Diane,5,NULL
```

Comment: You need to specify the column names explicitly while insert into the table which has identity column.

Comment: but in the csv file those values are there..and that is my requirement...SET IDENTITY_INSERT ABC ON ..is for that reason only i think...Is not there is any way to work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says, you need to specify the column names while inserting.

I don't think we have a option to specify the column names during bulk insert. You can use the below alternative.

```
 select * into dbo.Stagingtable from ABC where 1=2
    go

    BULK 
    INSERT Stagingtable
    FROM 'F:\test.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ABC ON
GO
    INSERT INto ABC (column1,column2,etc) 
    select * from Stagingtable
```

Answer (score 1):

James, you are getting error because your csv file contain 9 column values but your table structure contain 10 columns.. so thats why you are getting that error..
If you SET Identity_Insert ABC off
 then you will get no error

Answer (score 0):

From [Keep Identity Values When Bulk Importing Data (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx):

> To prevent SQL Server from assigning identity values while bulk
>   importing data rows into a table, use the appropriate keep-identity
>   command qualifier. When you specify a keep-identity qualifier, SQL
>   Server uses the identity values in the data file. These qualifiers are
>   as follows:

```
bcp                                          | -E             |  Switch
BULK INSERT                                  | KEEPIDENTITY   |  Argument
INSERT ... SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...) | KEEPIDENTITY   |  Table hint
```

The example shows how to apply this potion in your case:

```
BULK 
INSERT ABC
FROM 'F:\test.csv'
WITH
(
    KEEPIDENTITY,  
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: If some value is NULL, will it be an issue..as I am getting an error ...Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 9 (ii).

Comment: Please ask a separate question  for a different problem.